# "Too many errors" - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou recebendo a mensagem de `Too many errors` na **linha 113** de meu arquivo **Javascript** porém não encontro nenhum erro nesse arquivo, meu arquivo é o seguinte:

```
var x = 0;

var data = new Date();
var dia = data.getDate();
var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
var ano = data.getFullYear();
var hora = data.getHours();
var minuto = data.getMinutes();
var segundo = data.getSeconds();

if (dia.toString().length == 1){
    dia = "0"+dia;
}
if (mes.toString().length == 1){
    mes = "0"+mes;
}
if (hora.toString().length == 1){
    hora = "0"+hora;
}
if (minuto.toString().length == 1){
    minuto = "0"+minuto;
}
if (segundo.toString().length == 1){
    segundo = "0"+segundo;
}

var lista01 = [];
var lista02 = [];
var lista03 = [];
var lista04 = [];
var lista05 = [];
var lista06 = [];
var lista07 = [];
var lista08 = [];
var lista09 = [];
var lista10 = [];
var lista11 = [];
var lista12 = [];
var lista13 = [];
var lista14 = [];
var lista15 = [];
var lista16 = [];
var lista17 = [];
var lista18 = [];
var lista19 = [];
var lista20 = [];
var lista21 = [];
var lista22 = [];
var lista23 = [];
var lista24 = [];
var lista25 = [];
var lista26 = [];
var lista27 = [];
var lista28 = [];
var lista29 = [];
var lista30 = [];
var lista31 = [];
var lista32 = [];
var lista33 = [];
var lista34 = [];
var lista35 = [];
var lista36 = [];
var lista37 = [];
var lista38 = [];
var lista39 = [];
var lista40 = [];
var lista41 = [];
var lista42 = [];
var lista43 = [];
var lista44 = [];
var lista45 = [];
var lista46 = [];
var lista47 = [];
var lista48 = [];
var lista49 = [];
var lista50 = [];
var lista51 = [];
var lista52 = [];
var lista53 = [];
var lista54 = [];
var lista55 = [];
var lista56 = [];
var lista57 = [];
var lista58 = [];
var lista59 = [];
var lista60 = [];
var lista61 = [];
var lista62 = [];
var lista63 = [];
var lista64 = [];
var lista65 = [];
var lista66 = [];
var lista67 = [];
var lista68 = [];
var lista69 = [];
var lista70 = [];
var lista71 = [];
var lista72 = [];
var lista73 = [];
var lista74 = [];
var lista75 = [];
var lista76 = [];
var lista77 = [];
var lista78 = [];
var lista79 = [];
var lista80 = [];
var lista81 = [];
var lista82 = [];
var lista83 = [];
var lista84 = [];
var lista85 = [];
var lista86 = [];
var lista87 = [];
var lista88 = [];
var lista89 = [];
var lista90 = [];
var lista91 = [];
var lista92 = [];
var lista93 = [];
var lista94 = [];
var lista95 = [];
var lista96 = [];
var lista97 = [];
var lista98 = [];
var lista99 = [];
var lista100 = [];

var listaFinal = [];


if ($data.linha01a50 == 1){
    lista01.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie01);
    if($data.situacao01 === false && $data.formInput.peso01 !== null){
        lista01.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista01.push($data.formInput.laudo01);
    }
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].suprimento);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.defeito01.defeito);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.residuo01);
    lista01.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista01.push(false);
    lista01.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista01);
}
else if ($data.linha01a50 == 2){
    lista01.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie01);
    if($data.situacao01 === false && $data.formInput.peso01 !== null){
        lista01.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista01.push($data.formInput.laudo01);
    }
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].suprimento);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.defeito01.defeito);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.residuo01);
    lista01.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista01.push(false);
    lista01.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista01);
    lista02.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie02);
    if($data.situacao02 === false && $data.formInput.peso02 !== null){
        lista02.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista02.push($data.formInput.laudo02);
    }
    lista02.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista02.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].suprimento);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.defeito02.defeito);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.residuo02);
    lista02.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista02.push(false);
    lista02.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista02);
}
else if ($data.linha01a50 == 3){
    lista01.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie01);
    if($data.situacao01 === false && $data.formInput.peso01 !== null){
        lista01.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista01.push($data.formInput.laudo01);
    }
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].suprimento);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.defeito01.defeito);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.residuo01);
    lista01.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista01.push(false);
    lista01.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista01);
    lista02.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie02);
    if($data.situacao02 === false && $data.formInput.peso02 !== null){
        lista02.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista02.push($data.formInput.laudo02);
    }
    lista02.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista02.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].suprimento);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.defeito02.defeito);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.residuo02);
    lista02.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista02.push(false);
    lista02.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista02);
    lista03.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista03.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie03);
    if($data.situacao03 === false && $data.formInput.peso03 !== null){
        lista03.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista03.push($data.formInput.laudo03);
    }
    lista03.push($data.requestSuprimento03[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista03.push($data.requestSuprimento03[0].suprimento);
    lista03.push($data.formInput.defeito03.defeito);
    lista03.push($data.formInput.residuo03);
    lista03.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista03.push(false);
    lista03.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista03);
}
else if ($data.linha01a50 == 4){
    lista01.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie01);
    if($data.situacao01 === false && $data.formInput.peso01 !== null){
        lista01.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista01.push($data.formInput.laudo01);
    }
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].suprimento);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.defeito01.defeito);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.residuo01);
    lista01.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista01.push(false);
    lista01.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista01);
    lista02.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie02);
    if($data.situacao02 === false && $data.formInput.peso02 !== null){
        lista02.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista02.push($data.formInput.laudo02);
    }
    lista02.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista02.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].suprimento);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.defeito02.defeito);
    lista02.push($data.formInput.residuo02);
    lista02.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista02.push(false);
    lista02.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista02);
    lista03.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista03.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie03);
    if($data.situacao03 === false && $data.formInput.peso03 !== null){
        lista03.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista03.push($data.formInput.laudo03);
    }
    lista03.push($data.requestSuprimento03[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista03.push($data.requestSuprimento03[0].suprimento);
    lista03.push($data.formInput.defeito03.defeito);
    lista03.push($data.formInput.residuo03);
    lista03.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista03.push(false);
    lista03.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista03);
    lista04.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista04.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie04);
    if($data.situacao04 === false && $data.formInput.peso04 !== null){
        lista04.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista04.push($data.formInput.laudo04);
    }
    lista04.push($data.requestSuprimento04[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista04.push($data.requestSuprimento04[0].suprimento);
    lista04.push($data.formInput.defeito04.defeito);
    lista04.push($data.formInput.residuo04);
    lista04.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista04.push(false);
    lista04.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista04);
}
return {
    'listaRetorno':JSON.stringify(listaFinal),
    'loteEncerrado':false
};
```

O erro ocorre na linha: `var lista87 = [];`. Se tiverem alguma ideia de o que pode estar ocorrendo e como resolver.

Versão com um ARRAY:

```
else if ($data.linha01a50 == 2){
    lista01.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie01);
    if($data.situacao01 === false && $data.formInput.peso01 !== null){
        lista01.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista01.push($data.formInput.laudo01);
    }
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento01[0].suprimento);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.defeito01.defeito);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.residuo01);
    lista01.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista01.push(false);
    lista01.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista01);
    lista01 = [];
    lista01.push($data.numeroLote.value);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.numeroSerie02);
    if($data.situacao02 === false && $data.formInput.peso02 !== null){
        lista01.push("Vazio");
    } else {
        lista01.push($data.formInput.laudo02);
    }
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].nomeFornecedor);
    lista01.push($data.requestSuprimento02[0].suprimento);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.defeito02.defeito);
    lista01.push($data.formInput.residuo02);
    lista01.push(ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
    lista01.push(false);
    lista01.push($data.user.user_name.toUpperCase().replace('.',' '));
    listaFinal.push(lista01);
}
```

Comment: Você tem 100 arrays. Certamente que não estruturou o programa da maneira mais indicada. Se cada `$data.linha01a50` associa a uma lista, então o que quer é um dicionário.

Comment: Minha ideia é que depois eu una eles em um único array antes de mandar a informação

Comment: Você tem certeza que o código está todo aí? O único erro que apareceu aqui no console foi a declaração incorreta do `return` no fim do arquivo.

Comment: @avsinacio tenho certeza

Comment: A minha opinião e peço que não a leve a mal, é que o código como tem é absolutamente incomportável, e se ainda não lhe deu problemas, não faltará muito para acontecer. Comece por restruturar o programa da forma correta, mesmo antes de começar a corrigir outros problemas

Comment: O @Isac está correto, se possível reconsidere repensar as estruturas de dados para escrever um código mais bem estruturado.

Comment: @Isac tem razão, vou tentar usar um único array, poderia olhar a alteração que fiz na pergunta para ver se é válido?

Comment: Outra solução simples ainda no mesmo estilo da que tem seria fazer uma lista de listas, e com um `for` fazer `push` de 100 listas automaticamente. Não quer dizer que seja a melhor solução mas já é um ponto de partida.

Comment: @Isac eu tentei fazer com um for como você sugeriu porém não consegui que no segundo laço do for a minha variável `$data.formInput.numeroSerie01` mudasse para `$data.formInput.numeroSerie02` tu teria alguma ideia para que eu pudesse fazer isso? Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Se é esse o caso então isso deveria ser um array. Se é um campo do formulario então devia obter esses campos todos com JQuery ou com `querySelectorAll` para que tenha uma lista. Monte um fiddle com tudo que eu tento ajudar a estruturar